# Will the Data Explorer be formally announced?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, blog, beta-phase

I just discovered the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). It's pretty great! But it hasn't been formally announced on the Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange blog. Is there a reason for this? As far as I can tell from the [FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq) and the [about page](https://data.stackexchange.com/about), it's not in beta. But the only way one would know about it is by following Meta (which I haven't had much time to do lately, and a lot of Stack Overflow users don't do at all).

Comment: It was made by Waffles, not by Jeff and the team, that's why it was not formally announced. Jeff said that it will be integrated into Stack Exchange at one point, so just hold tight. There will probably also be a blog post about it then.

Comment: @alex thanks, i wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Re: It's pretty great ... thanks heaps!

Comment: @waffles Given all the work you put in, you deserve it. It really is quite a nice effort on your part!

Comment: This is really, really cool :) Thanks @waffles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of June 13th 2010, SEDE is officially announced, read all about it here: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/

Comment: Don't put a beta sticker on it, you'll never get it off.

Comment: I didn't realize it wasn't made by the team. Maybe you could mention that somewhere on the faq and/or about page? It certainly gives the impression of being first-party.

Comment: @Kip It will be first party, so I doubt it's worth making that change.

Comment: Can I suggest a RSS feed that simply indicates the version of the public DB dump in use?

Comment: @Tim, an easier way is just to subscribe to the blog, max 12 hours after the blog announces the data dump, it will be live on http://odata.stackexchange.com